# Failure posting data to database

Tags: mysql, node.js, xampp

I don't know why there is a problem with post function. It returns 
"Cannot GET /api/signup/email/password/nick".

But Get function is working properly

I cannot find any answers anywhere. I'm not familiar with backend development.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mysql = require('mysql');

var db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    database : "flatduties",
    password: ""
});

db.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
});


///////////// API //////////////

const router = express.Router();
app.use('/api', router);

router.get('/', (request, response) => {
    response.json({message: 'api v1 - projekt'});
});

router.post('/signup/:email/:passwrd/:nick', function(req, res, next) {  
var mail = req.params.email;
var pass = req.params.passwrd;
var nick = req.params.nick;

db.query("INSERT INTO `user`(`Email`, `Password`, `Nick`) VALUES  ('"+mail+"', '"+pass+"', '"+nick+"');", function (error, results,fields) {
  if(error){
    res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 500, "error": error, "response": null}));
  } else {
    res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 200, "error": null, "response": results}));
  }
});
});

router.get('/login/:email/:passwrd', function(req, res, next) {
  var email = req.params.email;
  var pass = req.params.passwrd;

  db.query("SELECT UserID, Email, Password, Nick, GroupID FROM user WHERE Email ='"+email+"' AND Password ='"+pass+"';", function (error, results, fields) {
  if(error){
    res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 500, "error": error, "response": null}));
  } else {
    res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 200, "error": null, "response": results}));
  }
});
});

app.listen(8888);
```

Comment: **WARNING**: Be sure to use *prepared statements with placeholder values* to avoid [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). This is necessary to ensure any values are properly escaped and won't cause problems. Most drivers have this capability, and those like [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com) make it easy so there's really no excuse to not do it.

Comment: **WARNING**: Storing plain-text passwords is a terrible habit to get into, even for test code. Putting them in the URL is **way, way worse**. There's no reason to ever, ever do this. Send these as regular POST params.

Comment: **WARNING**: When writing authentication in Node.js you probably want to use [Passport](http://www.passportjs.org) or something like it rather than rolling your own solution. Authentication is not an easy problem to solve, there's many subtle issues here, and for a taste of what you're up against have a look at the [myriad of security concerns](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries) you need to protect against.

Comment: Ok, but right now a have a problem that it don't find my path like:
http://localhost:8888/api/signup/email/pass/nick
And i don't know why

Comment: Right now what you have is recklessly dangerous code that should never be deployed. I'm sorry, but there's really nothing to be gained by fixing this approach. If you want to learn how to write an authentication system from scratch for educational purposes that's great, and we can help, but this is so not the way to do it.

Comment: A) Your form *must* be using POST. B) Your form *must* be submitting parameters as part of the form *body* and **absolutely not, never in the URL itself**. C) You *must* properly hash passwords. This is not optional in this day and age.

Answer (score 1):

@Tadman's warning rants in his comments are exactly right. The internet is crawling with cybercreeps just hoping somebody's website is insecure like yours. If this site is available to the world, it almost certainly will get pwned within a week.

On Stack Overflow we push hard when people do insecure things.  Why are we so adamant about it?  How do I know this kind of thing is dangerous?  It's a long and embarrassing story.

Never put a password in a URL like this

```
https://pwned.example.com/login/oskar%40example.com/secret
```

It will land in your web server log. Then you, and anybody who sees your logs, will know your users' passwords. Users really really don't like that.

To handle login stuff, I suggest you look at the [passport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport) extension to node / express.

To hash your passwords look at [bcrypt](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js).

All that being said:

You have this code.

```
router.post('/signup/:email/:passwrd/:nick', function(req, res, next) { /*unsafe*/
    var mail = req.params.email;
    var pass = req.params.passwrd;
    var nick = req.params.nick;
    db.query("INSERT....
```

What you want instead in your node / express program is more like this. You fetch the parameters from the body (the payload) of the POST operation.

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const saltRounds = 10;
...
router.post('/signup', function(req, res, next) {
    const mail = req.body.email;
    const pass = req.body.passwrd;
    const nick = req.body.nick;
    /* securely hash the password */
    bcrypt.hash(pass, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
       /* store hash, never pass, in your database. */
       db.query("INSERT ...
    });
 ...
```

Then, in your html you need something like this (not debugged, and definitely not styled nicely.)

```
 <form method="post" action="https://example.com/signup">
     <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email address" />
     <input type="password" name="passwrd" />
     <input type="text" name="nick" placeholder="Your nickname" />
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up Now" />
 </form>
```

When your user clicks Sign Up Now, the web browser will POST the form to your node / express app with the form-fields in the body, not the URL.